# Why am I getting this error and How can I correct it?

Tags: c#

```
form2 newF2;

newF2 myform = new NewF2();
myform.ShowDialog();
```

I have the above code.  I have a button in form1 that launches form2.

I get the following error message "The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have been trying to figure this out for about 2 hours and I have no clue why I am getting this error.  Both forms have the same namespace.  Any ideas?

Using the below code I also get the same error:

```
form2 myform = new form2();
myform.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Probably need to provide a bit more code. However, just looking at your code, I'm a bit confused by form2 newF2 / newF2 myform. It looks to me that you are confusing newF2 for a variable name and then for a type. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error.

```
form2 newF2;
```

This is declaring newF2 to be of type form2.

newF2 is a variable name and not a type.

You could fix it by

```
NewF2 myform = new NewF2();
```

or

```
var myForm = new NewF2();
```

I would examine the naming patterning you are using.  If form2 is a type the accepted C# standard is Form2, it will make it easier to tell types from variables name.

For more on C# coding guidlines please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

(Based on the code you showed) the line

```
newF2 myform = new NewF2();
```

should be

```
newF2 = new form2();
```

I suspect the code you have shown us is not what you actually have. What I suggest you change it to is this:

```
Form2 myForm = new Form2();
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: @Brandon: if it is a namespace issue then check you haven't got the problem described here (referencing the wrong .Net version): [VS2010 - Getting “type or namespace name could not be found” but everything seems ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304741/vs2010-getting-type-or-namespace-name-could-not-be-found-but-everything-seem/3304899#3304899)

Comment: And you should also ensure that Form2 is in a project or assembly that has been referenced from the project that contains the code you are writing.

Comment: How would you reference form2?

Comment: You need to add a reference to the project/assembly that contains it, this previous SO answer will show you how: [How to add a reference to a WinForm project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082167/how-to-add-a-reference-to-a-winform-project). I can't be more specific than that because I don't have you project in front of me.

Comment: So, I should find form2 in the bin folder of the "add reference box"?  I don't see a form2?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5181/discussion-between-brandon-and-slugster)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better post your form2 source code here.

Maybe the form2's namespace is different with the class where you call the form2