# session management in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, session, windows

I am looking for session management on my windows based application using vb.net. I google it, and found the similar result everywhere, and i got same error.

[Session Management in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/343007/session-in-windows-applcation-using-vb-net) 
[Session Management](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t61549-session-variables.html)

This is what i was trying to do

```
Session("UserId") = admin
```

Here `admin` is the variable, 
But, i got error in the above line, says Session is not declare. Need Help

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Session is the web's attempt to behave like a WinForms app with stateful memory. Are you trying to centralize the state of your application on a remote machine? If you're not, attempting to use Session in a WinForms application is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Session is a mechanism to store information about an user **only when you are in asp.net**.
Usually is used to store some global information/preferences that you need about the user is browsing, for example, the language that web pages should be presented to user.

Each user will have his own session values.

There are other mechanisms to achieve that as viewstate or cookies.

From the tags in your question seems you have a winform application. **You cannot use session on windows forms**. Usually windows forms applications are intended for one specific user. If you want to store global information/preferences in winforms you can use an static preferences class.

Comment: any links, where i can find the examples, which you are saying...??

Answer (score 0):

Session is part of the HTTPContext and is derived from System.Web.

Do you have a reference to System.Web?

See the following link for adding a reference to your application.

[How to add a reference to a WinForm project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082167/how-to-add-a-reference-to-a-winform-project)

Comment: No. So, you mean, i have to import the System.Web on my form. But, still it showing same error.

Comment: No add a reference to System.Web.dll in your references.

Answer (score 0):

session is availablein web application which is stateless. But in window application no need to use Session(not available in window application) because it is not stateless.If you want to use maintain at application level you can use static class.